# Where are iCloud Shared Album photos saved in Finder in macOS Monterey?

Tags: icloud, finder, photos

This question has been answered for older macOS versions, but not the latest release.

I am trying to locate where these iCloud Shared Album photos were saved to locate them in a backup so I can access the photos of an Album that was previously shared with me but no longer is.

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after posting this, I figured it out...

These photos are now located inside the Photos Library.photoslibrary (like they always should've been!)

For most users this will be here:

```
~/Pictures/Photos Library/scopes/cloudsharing/data/XXXXXXX
```

XXXXXXX is a number such as "186318857" and the photos are in folders respective to their albums, with unidentifiable IDs as names.